# OSGi - Activator can't access internal packages of the Bundle

Tags: android, eclipse, osgi, noclassdeffounderror, emf

I'm trying to run a small EMF-based application on Apache Felix. Felix is running on a Android Device. I'm using Eclipse but without bnd and without maven.

I got a EMF Bundle that exports the packages of:

```
org.eclipse.emf.common_droid-2.7.0.v20120127-1122.jar
org.eclipse.emf.ecore_droid-2.7.0.v20120127-1122.jar
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_droid-2.7.0.v20120127-1122.jar
```

The Structure of my Plugin-Project:

```
[+] src
---> com.androidosgi.notifier
---> com.androidosgi.notifier.notification
---> com.androidosgi.notifier.notification.impl
---> com.androidosgi.notifier.notification.util
[+] META-INF
---> MANIFEST.MF
Notification-1.0.ecore
Notification-1.0.ecorediag
Notification-1.0.ecorert
NotificationComponent.xmi
```

The Activator is in com.androidosgi.notifier.

The MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Notification Testing
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.androidosgi.notifier
Bundle-Version: 12.6.5
Bundle-Activator: com.androidosgi.notifier.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: Homer Simpson
Import-Package: 
 com.androidosgi.notifier.notification,
 com.androidosgi.notifier.notification.impl,
 com.androidosgi.notifier.notification.util,
 org.eclipse.emf.common,
 org.eclipse.emf.common.archive,
 org.eclipse.emf.common.command,
 org.eclipse.emf.common.notify,
 org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl,
 org.eclipse.emf.common.util,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.util,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.namespace,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.namespace.impl,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.namespace.util,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type.impl,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type.internal,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type.util,
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Export-Package: com.androidosgi.notifier;x-internal:=true,
 com.androidosgi.notifier.notification;x-internal:=true,
 com.androidosgi.notifier.notification.impl;x-internal:=true,
 com.androidosgi.notifier.notification.util;x-internal:=true
```

Before I installed the bundle on the OSGi, I "dexed" it and added the classes.dex to the bundle.

If I try to start i get: NoClassDefFoundError
[image]

Any ideas or solutions ? :) Thanks

Comment: Looking at your manifest, why is your bundle exporting so many of its internal packages?

Have you got a stack trace for the exception? Is EMF using reflection to load your bundle's internal classes?

When you run outside Android, are you using Equinox or Felix?

Comment: the imports of internal packages was just a try to make it work. Before that i had a version without internal packages and no exports.
I'm not sure whether EMF reflections used, but I think so. Equinox, but now i changed again back to felix. THANK YOU !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok 50% is done ;-) It is running on a computer (Java 1.6) (but still not on Android) ! The NoClassDefFoundError Error caused in my case by the missing versioning stuff. I added the version in every package in the exporting EMF-Bundle(b1). I also added the version ranges on every package at the importing Notifier-Bundle(b2). **Looks like that is very important to set the versions.** 
I also removed:

> com.androidosgi.notifier.notification, 
>   com.androidosgi.notifier.notification.impl, 
>   com.androidosgi.notifier.notification.util,

from the imports of the Bundle(b2) and all export from (b2).
Its running now on Apache Felix.

Uhh, I also added

> Import-Package:
>   org.xml.sax.helpers;version="[0.0.0.1_006_JavaSE,3.0.0)"

to the manifest of the Bundle (b1), the EMF-Bundle.

My next problem is that the exports of the standard systembundle in android seems to be diffrent as it is on a normal computer (used the command "headers" to find out). I will start a new Question for that an post the link here.

Answer (score 0):

EMF will not run on Felix, or any OSGi framework other than Equinox. See the following bug that I raised about this a long time ago: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=328227

You have to use a re-packaging of EMF that does the OSGi declarations properly. I have this on GitHub but it is slightly stale now, i.e. it packages an old version of EMF. See: https://github.com/njbartlett/emf-osgi

**UPDATE**: I was too hasty, that probably wasn't the right answer. It looks like you already repackaged EMF.

I suspect that the answer is you're importing the package `com.androidosgi.notifier.notification` and its subpackages, but those are probably packages inside your bundle. You should not import packages that are actually part of your bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the Update Neil, the re-packing was inspired by your github repo ;) but i had some problems with bnd so i did it my way. I removed the packages from the imports. Same Problem :-((

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have already checked the obvious things: 
* The class NotificationFactory is present inside the bundle 
* There are no typos in the name and path
* The class is not in an internal jar or smth like that
* The activator is found successfully by the system? 
* You have tried removing the imports?

The only more bizarre thing I can propose to check is whether maybe the problem is not with NotificationFactory itself, but with some class it uses. I've had such cases in other setups where the ClassNotFound was actually for another class inside the reported class.

Try for example moving the activator in the com.androidosgi.notifier.notification package - just as a check whether it will be found at all. In this way you will know whether the problem is with the package or with the class itself.